# sed command replacing string that contains special character is not working

Tags: shell, sed

i want to replace a special string inside a file.txt. my strings are like this :
-> Old String

```
tech=/lsf/dfg/a.v,/ldf/fgh/b.v
```

-> New String

```
tech=$var
```

i have tried following

```
sed -i 's/tech=/lsf/dfg/a.v,/ldf/fgh/b.v/tech=$var/g' file.txt
```

it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's#tech=/lsf/dfg/a.v,/ldf/fgh/b.v#tech=$var#g' file.txt
```

Just replace the delimiters '/' for the sed expression with '#' (or another character that is not in the string you are trying to match and replace).